# Associate hammerJS/jQuery events to default jQuery binding without $obj.hammer()

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, requirejs, marionette, hammer.js

I'm using Backbone.Marionette and RequireJS with a hammerJS implementation and have tried using backbone.hammer, but get the following error in an ItemView:

`Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'undelegateHammerEvents'`

I'm not exactly sure why this occurs, perhaps improper Backbone.View extension or improper require dependency delegation by me. I don't know. But with that reason being said, I'd like to just tie hammer events to jQuery using its default event binding, so that I can do something like:

`$('.myElement').on('dragstart', handler);`

Rather than:

`$('.myElement').hammer().on('dragstart', handler);`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

This answer is probably a bit late to help you, but maybe someone else can benefit.

You need to ensure backbone.hammer is loaded *before* Marionette (and it need only be loaded once). backbone.hammer (sounds painful, doesn't it?) extends "in place" (i.e., directly modifies) `Backbone.View`--which, as you may know, is the base class for `Marionette.View`.

So if Marionette gets loaded *before* backbone.hammer, `Marionette.View` will be extending the "virgin" `Backbone.View` rather than the hammer-ified version you want, and backbone.hammer's modifications will be effectively lost (unless you use a `Backbone.View` directly).

This same problem with backbone.hammer was reported as a bug the day before you posted your question. See the discussion here:

https://github.com/wookiehangover/backbone.hammer/issues/2

There are various ways you could ensure that backbone.hammer is loaded synchronously *before* Marionette. The easiest (and crudest) way would be to simply edit Marionette's source to add backbone.hammer as a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

You can try overriding jQuery's "on" method:

```
var originalOn = $.fn.on;
$.fn.on = function() {
  return originalOn.apply(this.hammer(), arguments);
}
```

Then you can use it like you described, without "hammer()" on every call

Comment: Incidentally, that's essentially what the `jquery-hammer` plug-in (from the hammerJS developer) does. `jquery-hammer` happens to be a dependency of `backbone.hammer`, which the OP was having trouble getting to work.